# Am I able to calculate SHAP directly for my testing dataset?

Tags: python, boosting, shapley-value

I trained an XGBoost classifier model on a training set, and I predicted it on the  testing set. I also calculated the respective class prediction values. I concatenated X_test and y_test together. I was wondering if I can place filters on this test dataset, and will I have to split this concatenated testing set again and fit another XGBoost model for SHAP analysis?